# Related models with conditions in Phalcon

Tags: orm, model, phalcon

How to setup filtering on related model data using `$this->hasMany()` or `$this->hasOne()` in model?

For instance:

I have SomeData table which can be referenced to ModalA or ModelB.
In ModelA and ModelB i have:

```
$this->hasMany(array('id', 'SomeData', 'foreign_key');
```

In ModelA I want to get all SomeData where `SomeData.foreign_key = id and SomeData.model = "ModelA"`.

I can easily get them with:

```
$this->getRelated(
    'SomeData',
     array("model = :model:", 'bind' => array('model' => 'ModelA')
);
```

but `$modelA->SomeData` gives me SomeData for ModelA and ModelB.

I've tried adding conditions in `$this->hasMany()` but without any luck.

Comment: This kind of filtering in relations is not yet supported. Feel free to add a NFR in the Github Issues page (https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon) :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will soon post an NFR with details :)

Comment: As "workaround" you could use PHQL (http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html) and add a function (e.g.) $modelA->getSomeDatas() which returns a Model\ResultInterface

Comment: Anybody know if it is now supported or is planned? I'm very interested :)

Comment: You can check here: https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/926#issuecomment-43251939. For now it looks like guys are busy finishing 2.0 which involves rewriting Phalcon in Zephir, so maybe after 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    // get what question ids are in test
    $ids_already_in_test = $this->getDI()
       ->get('modelsManager')->createBuilder()
       ->from('Model_QuestionToTest')
       ->columns(array('question_id'))
       ->andWhere('Model_QuestionToTest.test_id = :test_id:', array('test_id' =>  
                                   $search_options['not_in_test']))
       ->getQuery()
       ->execute();
    // filter out these ids
    $ids = array();
    foreach ($ids_already_in_test as $id) {
        $ids[] = (int) $id->question_id;
    }
    unset($ids_already_in_test);
    if (count($ids))
        $questions_query->notInWhere('Model_UserQuestion.id', $ids);
    }
```

there are 2 steps:
1) get ids, what you don't or do need
2) get results from this ids set with "notInWhere" or "inWhere" in the main query

Comment: I think that my question was about something different ;). Anyway - as some of comments stated this is not implemented in current version of Phalcon.

Comment: yes, it's not possible yet :) I just wanted to show you some other ways to get job done, while it's not yet supported by the framework